# Prevent GMail marking replies to clients as promotions or updates (not spam)

Tags: email, gmail

**Edit**: my question was marked as duplicate of "How can I prevent my mail from being classified as spam?". My messages are not classified as spam but updates or promotions. Setting SPF, domain keys, not using fake address or putting unsubscribe link was solution to question of which my question is allegedly duplicate.

I run a website with a simple contact form. Client asks a question, system sends it via email to official company's mail, and somebody answers the question. Reply is sent directly to client's email (TO field, not CC or BCC) from company's main email address.

We have a lot of complaints that we don't reply to emails, but we do. After short investigation it came out that our replies are marked by GMail as promotions or updates and are not shown in clients' inboxes.

Problem is we do not send adverts etc, we have commercial email account and provider doesn't add anything to our emails. Replies are send via provider's mail server.

Typical message looks like:

> TO: client's-mail@gmail.com
>
> FROM: office@company-domain.com
>
> Re: Question asked by contact form
>
> Hello,
>   This is my reply to client, written by human.
>
> Jane Doe, Company-name
>   Street 12345
>   Postal-Code City Country
>   tel.+00 000 000 000
>   fax: +00 000 000 000
>   www.company-domain.com
>
> The information transmitted is intended only for the person or company to which it is addressed and
>   may contain confidential and privileged material.  Any
>   review,dissemination, retransmission, or other use of, or taking of
>   any action in reliance upon, this information by persons or companies
>   other than the intended recipient is prohibited. If you received this
>   in error, please contact the sender and delete the material from any computer.
>
> -----here is the same info about about privileged materials, but in polish----
>
> 7 nov 2014 o 18:14 Client  wrote:
>
> Hi, this is my question.

What shall I do to prevent GMail from marking my messages as promotions and put my messages to client's inbox? Why message like this is classified as promotion anyway? We do not send newsletters or send mass correspondence.

Comment: Spam is defined as "unsolicited commercial email".   "Updates and promotions" is just a fancy word for spam.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for your reply. As the mail is send by my hosting provider's mail server and I can't set new SPF or domain keys, I can't attach unsubscribe link, 'cause it's not a subscription and I can't stop using fake email address, 'cause I don't use fake email address... the only solution is to change mail service provider? My messages are far away from being "unsolicited".